# Python linting: limit/ensure library only imported in one location

Tags: python, import, lint

I have a condition where I import a library `foo` in my application and make some configuration modifications to it. This occurs in, let's say, `tools/__init__.py`.

I then intend to only import that modified version elsewhere in my application (e.g. `from tools import foo` instead of `import foo`). I'd like to enforce this pattern via linting.

Looking for suggestions on how to ensure that everywhere else in my codebase, `import foo` is not used/does not occur, and only the version from `tools` is.

Comment: Once you have imported module `foo`, future imports of `foo` do not read the file again.  They go to the loaded module list and pull the module object from there.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you - you are right. The changes made to the library import in the init file were present in the other files even when making a "direct import" (rather than from `tools`). This accomplished the intended goal of ensuring the modification was available throughout the codebase.